# Is there a way to avoid the reading of my website's javascript directly in apache?

Tags: apache

I installed apache (last version) inside ubuntu (last version).
I then created a simple website.
My question is this, if the user using the website goes to a specific link, for example:

https://mywebsite.com/javascript/main.js

will be able to read the file inside.
I disabled browing so it's not possible to go to https://mywebsite.com/javascript/ and browse, but if he finds out the file name he can read it.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you *want* the Javascript to be executed as part of your website? Then the browser and hence the user *must* be able to read it. If not, don’t publicize it on a web server.

Comment: yes I do want to use JS. I was just wondering if it was normal...I thought that with some luck (or some extra tool) my website could be copied?

Comment: Yes, your website *can* be copied. That's a basic fact of web development.

Comment: @lorife, see my answer. Whatever that is available to the browser can be copied, just whatever that is available to the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR, When you want to run the JavaScript on your page, you have to make it available to everyone. What ever is available to the browser can be copied, no matter what.

---

When you add the `<script>` tag, for example, where the domain is https://example.com:

```
<script src="/myscripts.js"></script>
```

The browser makes a HTTP request to the page https://example.com/myscripts.js, and the web server returns the headers and the body, for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 Jan 2021 13:57:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Nov 2020 19:22:59 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1996
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8


alert("Hi, there!");
```

And, the web server sees the `Content-Type:` header, and then, if the header is `application/javascript` for example, it parses the body as JavaScript. The body starts after the two lines after the header.

Now, there is no way to know if the browser itself is requesting the page, or the person is. Because, all the pages are requested by the browser, no matter if the person types in the website name, or if the browser itself requests it without the person telling it to.

If you really do not want the user to view the JavaScript page, you will have to design your own browser, and make your users use it.

It is the same for images too. It is the same for any file that is publicly available in your server.